# getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection | Input is disappearing automatically - flutter Textfield

Tags: flutter, dart

I have two textfield .One for title(String) another one is for amount(double).when I want to input in title field input shows perfectly. After finishing input when I start to put input on second field (amount), title field's input disappeared. and another thing happened , can't able to write something in Amount field. But when I tap amount field manually again(second time) it can able to take input.

after going again title field to input something , amount field disappeared again.

some warning shows on terminal which are attached below

Warning:

```
    I/AssistStructure( 9566): Flattened final assist data: 444 bytes, containing 1 windows, 3 views
W/IInputConnectionWrapper( 9566): getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper( 9566): getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper( 9566): getTextAfterCursor on inactive InputConnection
I/AssistStructure( 9566): Flattened final assist data: 444 bytes, containing 1 windows, 3 views
```

Input Field:

```
        TextField(
          controller: titleController,
          decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Title'),
          onSubmitted: (_) => submitData(),
        ),
        TextField(
          controller: amountController,
          decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Amount'),
          keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
          onSubmitted: (_) => submitData(),
        ),
        TextButton(
            child: Text('Add Transaction'),
            style: TextButton.styleFrom(
              primary: Colors.purple,
            ),
            onPressed: submitData),
```

Function:

```
 final titleController = TextEditingController();
 final amountController = TextEditingController();

 submitData() {
final enteredTitle = titleController.text;
final enteredAmount = double.parse(amountController.text);
if (enteredTitle.isEmpty || enteredAmount <= 0) {
  return;
}
addTx(
  enteredTitle,
  enteredAmount,
);
}
```

Comment: can you include full sample widget from build method

Comment: did you mean image of the ui?

Comment: nope, a sample full widget that will reproduce the same error, More about [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)